# Newton's method in higher dimensions

Tags: numerical-methods, newton-raphson, numerical-calculus

To calculate the inverse of a quadratic matrix A, we could solve the equation
$F(X):=X^{-1}-A=0$.

I need to show that if X is invertable, then $DF(X)(\Delta X)=-X^{-1}\Delta XX^{-1}$ where DF(X) is the Frechét derivative of F.

My idea would have been to use the standard recursive formula $x_{k+1}=x_k-\frac{f(x_k)}{f'(x_k)}$, then transform to $f'$ and plug in the matrices but that didn't really work out. What could I do?

Comment: So is this a question of computing the derivative of $X \mapsto X^{-1}$. This has been answered before on this site: https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=derivative+of+matrix+inverse But to the context of the question: why are you using an algorithm that requires computing an inverse in order to compute an inverse?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for, but Newton's method in higher dimensions is the same formula you gave just with the x's as vectors and instead of $1/f'(x_k)$ it is $DF^{-1}(x_k)$.

Comment: Suppose I had computed the derivative of the matrix inverse, how would I then go back to $DF^{-1}$?

Comment: @TrevorGunn I think you'd need $(DF)^{-1} = -(\Delta X) A$, so wouldn't need to compute any inverses to run the algorithm, assuming OP's expression for $DF$ is correct

Comment: @Joe Ah, thanks for the notice! I've corrected the expression for DF.

Comment: @Joe you need the inverse of $(DF)_X$ not the inverse of $(DF)_X(\Delta X)$. If we vectorize the expression with the tensor product, we have $\operatorname{vec}[(DF)_X \Delta X] = (-X^{-\top} \otimes X^{-1}) \operatorname{vec}(\Delta X)$ and we need to compute the inverse of $(-X^{-\top} \otimes X^{-1})$.

Comment: @Joe $X^{-\top} = (X^{-1})^{\top} = (X^{\top})^{-1}$ and $(A \otimes B)^{-1} = A^{-1} \otimes B^{-1}$. The whole thing simplifies to $X_{k + 1} = 2X_k - X_k A X_k$.

Comment: @TrevorGunn It is also worth pointing out that the choice of $X_0$ is critical to the convergence of this particular iteration.  The following choice works
$$X_0 = \frac{A^T}{\|A\|^2_F}$$

Answer (score 1):

With matrix functions it is better to compute the Newton step $S$ in $X_{+1}=X+S$ as the solution of the linear system resulting from the tangent root equation
$$
0=F(X)+DF(X)[S]=X^{-1}-A-X^{-1}SX^{-1}.
$$
Otherwise you would need to translate everything into $n^2$ long column vectors where then the derivative is a $n^2\times n^2$ matrix.

Comment: So is the point to then multiply on both sides by $X$ and write $X - XAX - S = 0$? Then $X_{+1}=2X - XAX$ to run the algorithm? What would be a good starting point, $A$ or the identity matrix maybe?

Comment: As in the scalar case, $\|I-AX\|<1$ would be nice to have for the initial point.

Comment: Is that a condition for convergence? And you're saying that any point that satisfies that condition could be used? Then I think you would need $p(A,I)$ a (preferably low order) polynomial which satisfies that condition, to be able to actually run the algorithm in practise. Any idea about such a $p$?

Comment: To find an efficient starting point is already more complicated than that in the scalar case. You can look up similar procedures in the more serious case of the iterative computation of the polar decomposition of a matrix. Matrix inversion happens quite rarely in numerical practice, in most cases matrix factorization is enough for equation solving.